# simplexml_load_string correct parameters for namespace

Tags: php, xml

I am currently trying to pull information from the google contacts api.  Using the sample code provided in the libraries:

```
$response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody())); 
$result = json_decode($response, true);
```

the `simplexml_load_string` function does not pick up on namespaces. Looking at php.net and how to add the parameters I am a little lost.

```
$xml = json_encode(simplexml_load_string(null, $val->getResponseBody(), null, 'gd', true));
```

event with trying to pull the 'gd' namespace from my xml string I am receiving an error.  Is there anyone who can assist in this?

The output error is this:

> simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 2 to be a class name derived from SimpleXMLElement

But on top of this error it also correctly prints the info I want...I am confused.

Example of info I need to pull:

```
<gd:extendedProperty xmlns:gs='http://schemas.google_apps_sync.com' name='google_apps_sync'>
    <gs:em_odn1>awalker@xxxxx.com</gs:em_odn1>
    <gs:em_dn1>First Name Last Name</gs:em_dn1>
    <gs:em_ad1>awalker@xxxxxxxxx.com</gs:em_ad1>
    <gs:em_t1>SMTP</gs:em_t1>
    <gs:f_c>32791</gs:f_c>
    <gs:f>Last, First</gs:f>
  </gd:extendedProperty>
```

EDIT

```
$xmlResponse = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody(), null, 0, 'gd', true);
$xmlResponse->registerXPATHNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google_apps_sync.com');
$xmlResponse->registerXPATHNamespace('gs', 'http://schemas.google_apps_sync.com/contact/2008');
```

The above code allows me to access the namespaces that I need, but only one at a time....for instance:

```
$email = json_encode($xmlResponse->xpath('//gd:email'), true));
$postal = json_encode($xmlResponse->xpath('//gd:postalAddress'), true);
$name = json_encode($xmlResponse->xpath('//gs:em_dn1'), true);
```

if I print these variables I get the respective information I need, but is there not a way for me to access the original `$xmlResponse` variable after I have initiated the namespaces that I want?

ex:

```
json_decode($xmlResponse, true);
```

Won't give me the xml information with the namespaces I have defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found after hours of combing info on stackoverflow and relatively undocumented on google... if you add `?alt=json` to the end of your contacts api uri you will receive the response in JSON!

Comment: The question asked for more information on using simplexml_load_string, suggesting that one should change the response type doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what is says in the manual

[PHP.NET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
simplexml_load_file ( string $filename [, string $class_name = "SimpleXMLElement" [, int $options = 0 [, string $ns = "" [, bool $is_prefix = false ]]]] )
$xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody(),null, 0, 'gd', true);
$xml =json_encode($xml);
```

**UPDATE**

you are not using the namespace correctly, please show the all your xml structure.

On the example you showed, the namespace `gd` is not defined. you will need something like this to make it work:

```
<item xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google_apps_sync.com'> 
   <gd:extendedProperty xmlns:gs='http://schemas.google_apps_sync.com'..>
   ...
   </gd:extendedProperty>
</item>
```

Now you can use

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody(),null, 0, 'gd', true);
```

and when you want to access the `gs` namespace you can use

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("gs", 'http://schemas.google_apps_sync.com');
```

Comment: This wasn't necessarily constructive at all.  I have read that and found it confusing as there are no example of actually passing parameters.

Comment: The result from this is a blank array as well.

Comment: Maybe you should analyze the content of `$val->getResponseBody()` are you getting the data you are expecting?

Comment: Yup, thats where I pulled the xml from.

Comment: I have made some progress and added that to the original question.  Please have a look I am almost there.

Comment: This returns an empty array for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the elements with namespaces using children. For example:

```
<people xmlns:ns="http://something.com/ns">
<person><ns:name>Amy</ns:name></person>
<person><ns:name>Bill</ns:name></person>
</people>

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo $xml->person[0]->children("http://something.com/ns")->name; // will echo Amy
```

Answer (score 0):

This load all data from all namespaces :

```
function xmlToArray($xml, $options = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        'namespaceSeparator' => ':',//you may want this to be something other than a colon
        'attributePrefix' => '@',   //to distinguish between attributes and nodes with the same name
        'alwaysArray' => array(),   //array of xml tag names which should always become arrays
        'autoArray' => true,        //only create arrays for tags which appear more than once
        'textContent' => '$',       //key used for the text content of elements
        'autoText' => true,         //skip textContent key if node has no attributes or child nodes
        'keySearch' => false,       //optional search and replace on tag and attribute names
        'keyReplace' => false       //replace values for above search values (as passed to str_replace())
    );
    $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);
    $namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
    $namespaces[''] = null; //add base (empty) namespace
    //get attributes from all namespaces
    $attributesArray = array();
    foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
        foreach ($xml->attributes($namespace) as $attributeName => $attribute) {
            //replace characters in attribute name
            if ($options['keySearch']) $attributeName =
                   str_replace($options['keySearch'], $options['keyReplace'], $attributeName);
            $attributeKey = $options['attributePrefix']
                    . ($prefix ? $prefix . $options['namespaceSeparator'] : '')
                    . $attributeName;
            $attributesArray[$attributeKey] = (string)$attribute;
 
        }
 
    }
 
  
 
    //get child nodes from all namespaces
 
    $tagsArray = array();
 
    foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
 
        foreach ($xml->children($namespace) as $childXml) {
 
            //recurse into child nodes
 
            $childArray = xmlToArray($childXml, $options);
 
            list($childTagName, $childProperties) = each($childArray);
 
  
 
            //replace characters in tag name
 
            if ($options['keySearch']) $childTagName =
 
                    str_replace($options['keySearch'], $options['keyReplace'], $childTagName);
 
            //add namespace prefix, if any
 
            if ($prefix) $childTagName = $prefix . $options['namespaceSeparator'] . $childTagName;
 
  
 
            if (!isset($tagsArray[$childTagName])) {
 
                //only entry with this key
 
                //test if tags of this type should always be arrays, no matter the element count
 
                $tagsArray[$childTagName] =
 
                        in_array($childTagName, $options['alwaysArray']) || !$options['autoArray']
 
                        ? array($childProperties) : $childProperties;
 
            } elseif (
 
                is_array($tagsArray[$childTagName]) && array_keys($tagsArray[$childTagName])
 
                === range(0, count($tagsArray[$childTagName]) - 1)
 
            ) {
 
                //key already exists and is integer indexed array
 
                $tagsArray[$childTagName][] = $childProperties;
 
            } else {
 
                //key exists so convert to integer indexed array with previous value in position 0
 
                $tagsArray[$childTagName] = array($tagsArray[$childTagName], $childProperties);
 
            }
 
        }
 
    }
 
  
 
    //get text content of node
 
    $textContentArray = array();
 
    $plainText = trim((string)$xml);
 
    if ($plainText !== '') $textContentArray[$options['textContent']] = $plainText;
 
  
 
    //stick it all together
 
    $propertiesArray = !$options['autoText'] || $attributesArray || $tagsArray || ($plainText === '')
 
            ? array_merge($attributesArray, $tagsArray, $textContentArray) : $plainText;
 
    //return node as array
    return array(
        $xml->getName() => $propertiesArray
    );
}
```